# Getting an error when redirecting to an url after object creation in Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting the below error message when going to create an object with generic "CreateView" function.

"Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 4}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"

```
    # view function
class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['album_title', 'artist', 'genre', 'album_logo']        

# Model    
class Album(models.Model):
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='Image')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + '-' + self.artist

    # Url
```

url(r'^album/add/$',  views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py`? At first sight, it looks like there is no name with `detail` in the `music` app.

Comment: url(r'^album/add/$',  views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),

Comment: So where is the URL for the "detail" view?

Comment: @SubhajitPodder: but that is a `url` with name `'album-add'`. Where is the path to which you reference?

Comment: please add the url definition which has the `name="detail"`.